# Error Code 6398 - Critical

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, active-directory, active-directory-import

This error code keeps showing up and now Active Directory users can no longer edit documents etc., on SharePoint! Please Help!

[image: Error Code 6398 - Critical]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you do the following in that order:

1. You might find more information by checking timer job history under Monitoring in Central Administration.
2. Check ULS logs.
3. Stop-Start User Profile/Synchronization Service.
4. Reprovision User Profile Service via PowerShell.

If that doesn't help and you don't find the cause of the issue, you could recreate the User Profile Service Application. There is a really useful guide on that: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx . It's for SharePoint 2010, but there isn't a big difference between 2013. Fixing User Profile Service can sometimes be a real pain.

Comment: I keep getting the following under "Timer Job Status" "This timer job will run at the specified interval to synchronize user, group and group membership changes between the User Profile Application and specified directory source (such as Active Directory or LDAP). Synchronization will look for changes since the last time this job was run and only perform these changes for AD and LDAP sources."